# Google Apps Script .setvalues For loop not working

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The goal of the loop is to fill each cell over 797 rows across 5 columns A, B, C, D and E with a formula whose cell reference increments by 1.

E.g. Column A rows 6 onwards will have formula "=indirect("'Data Repository'!A3++")"

Column B rows 6 onwards will have formula "=indirect("'Data Repository'!B3++")"

What happens when I run the function however is it only fills in column A. I've checked the execution transcript and execution succeeded is logged after the first column has been filled up. I've tried various variations to no avail.

Below is the last variation I've tested:

```
function indirect(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Fleet - Weekly V3");
  var formulaArray = [];
  var columns = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
  var row = 2;
  var text = '=indirect(\"\'Data Repository\'!';
  var headerRow = 6;
  var column;

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    column = parseInt(i) + 1;
    formula = text + columns[i];
    for(i = 0; i < 797; i++) {
      row += 1;
      if (formulaArray.length == 797) {
        sheet.getRange(headerRow, column).offset(0, 0, formulaArray.length).setValues(formulaArray);
      } else {
        formulaArray.push([formula + row + '")']);
      }  
      Logger.log(formulaArray.length);
    }
    Logger.log(i)
    formulaArray = [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where you might be making an error - you need to create the variable i (var i = 0 instead of just i = 0) and if you're nesting loops, you need to have different variables increasing (first loop use i, then nest with j, then nest in that with k etc as needed)

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  column = parseInt(i) + 1;
  formula = text + columns[i];
   for(var j = 0; j < 797; j++) {
```

Untested but I believe it should work if you just substitute that in.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your loops. You are using the 'i' variable twice. Change the for loop that you have nested to iterate over the variable 'j' or something other than 'i'.